# Error in Pythagorean Theorem Program

Tags: java, pythagorean

I am making a Pythagorean theorem program to solve for a missing side, and if the user enters 0 as the value that means that that is the missing side to solve for. My program is not getting the correct answer. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class pythagTheorem {
  static double a;
  static double b;
  static double c;
  static double newa;
  static double newb;
  static double newc;   

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the value of a");
     a=scan.nextDouble();
     scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the value of b");
     b=scan.nextDouble();
     scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the value of c");
     c=scan.nextDouble();
     scan.nextLine();
     if(a==0)
     {
         newb=Math.pow(b, b);
         newc=Math.pow(c, c);
         double result=newc-newb;
         newa=Math.sqrt(result);        
     }      
     System.out.println("The value of a is " + newa);
  }
}
```

Comment: What values did you enter, what result did you get, and what did you expect it to be?

Comment: newb=Math.pow(b, b); should be newb=Math.pow(b, 2). Same for c.  The Math.pow is ( number,  power )

Comment: I actually just fixed, it thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So the problem I see with this Java code would be that it doesn't necessarily follow the actual pythagorean theorem. I see that if (A==0) then execute the actual equation, but you must remember that variable A isn't the hypotenuse of the triangle!

A^2 + B^2 = C^2 (C being the hypotenuse)  If you want to make it so that it finds any part of the triangle you must remember to derive the equation so that you can find the missing side! Such as, you have side A and C but you want to find side B, the equation would then be B^2 = C^2-A^2.

Last of all, I see you have newb=Math.pow(b, b); that would power your variable to itself! Even the the powers are only 2, so it would be newb=Math.pow(b, 2);

TIP! Remember to capitalize the second word in a variable name like numa to numA

```
/* REMEMBER THAT A NUMBER MUST NEVER BE GREAT THAN C UNLESS IT IS THE UNKNOWN OR YOU WILL ENCOUNTER A NONREAL NUMBER BECAUSE YOU CAN'T SQUARE ROOT A NEGATIVE NUMBER*/
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.lang.Math;

    public class pythagTheorem {

        static double a;
        static double b;
        static double c;
        static double newa;
        static double newb;
        static double newc;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a ZERO for the unknown side!");

            System.out.println("Enter the value of side A :: ");
            a = scan.nextDouble(); 

            System.out.println("Enter the value of B :: ");
            b = scan.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter the value of C :: ");
            c = scan.nextDouble();

            if (a == 0) {

                newc = Math.pow(c, 2);
                newb = Math.pow(b, 2);

                newa = Math.sqrt(newc - newb);

                System.out.println("Your missing side is :: " + newa);

            }
            else if(b == 0){

                newc = Math.pow(c, 2);
                newa = Math.pow(a, 2);

                newb = Math.sqrt(newc - newa);

                System.out.println("Your missing side is :: " + newb);
            }
            else if(c == 0){

                newa = Math.pow(a, 2);
                newb = Math.pow(b, 2);

                newc = Math.sqrt(newa + newb);

                System.out.println("Your missing side is :: " + newc);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Sorry! There is an error!");


        }
    }
```